# php code to generate text files that fetches contents from a mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, text-files

I have written a php code that creates a text file and stores the contents of a myssql table in a row by row basis. 
The code i wrote is

```
<?php
session_start();
include "functions.php";
db_connect();
$winners=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM winners") or die(mysql_error());
//creates a .txt file
$fp = fopen("myText.txt","wb");
while($winner=mysql_fetch_array($winners))
{
 $event=$winner['Event'];
 $position=$winner['Position'];
$name=$winner['Name'];
$college=$winner['College'];

$current = "$position $event $name $college";
file_put_contents($fp,$current,FILE_APPEND);
}
fclose($fp);
?>
```

The o/p i am getting is a blank text file with no contents.

The o/p i am expecting is a text file with the contents like

```
1 Sam   SUDOKU       MIT
2 David BASKETBALL   OXFORD
```

I am a beginner in php and i'm not able to find out the problem with my piece of code???

Comment: what is `db_connect()`?

Comment: Also, are you sure you don't want to use `$fp = fopen("myText.txt","a");`? wb isn't an accepted mode as far as I know, and if you're looking to append, using w truncates the file to 0 length.

Comment: in while(**$winner**=mysql_fetch_array($winners)) $winner is 2D ...try like $winner[0]['Event']

Answer (score 0):

file_put_contents uses a string as the first parameter, not a file pointer.

Use fwrite instead.

```
while($winner=mysql_fetch_assoc($winners))
{
 $event=$winner['Event'];
 $position=$winner['Position'];
 $name=$winner['Name'];
 $college=$winner['College'];

 $current = "$position $event $name $college";
 fwrite($fp,$current );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the code. The new code i wrote is:

```
$winners=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM winners") or die(mysql_error());
//creates a .txt file
$fp = fopen("myText.txt","a+");
$top = 'Position' . "\t" . 'Event' . "\t" . 'Name' . "\t" . 'College' . "\n";
fwrite($fp,$top);

while($winner=mysql_fetch_array($winners))
{
$event=$winner['Event'];
 $position=$winner['Position'];
$name=$winner['Name']; 
$college=$winner['College'];

$contents="$position" . "\t" . "$event" . "\t" . "$name" . "\t" . "$college" . "\n";
fwrite($fp,$contents);

}
fclose($fp);
```

and the o/p i got is

```
Position Name  Event        College
1        Sam   SUDOKU       MIT
2        David BASKETBALL   OXFORD
```